# Best way to create bulk entities in BreezeJS?

Tags: breeze

I am using a local JSON file to create entities in Breeze JS like this (inside a for loop).

```
var newCust = manager.createEntity('Clients', clients[i]);
```

Is there another way to do bulk insert with faster import times?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought. No idea if it would work but what about using breeze query to get the data in.
something like:-

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('file:///c:/temp/myfile.json');
return manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data){
    return data.results;
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can specify a file name in `from` clause. It take resource name only.

Comment: yes, you are right, I was thinking along the lines of using ajax to load the file and using the normal processes of the EntityManager to create the entities, but its probably not possible because of the sandboxed nature of the a browser.

Comment: @NathanFisher This is possible if you serve the JSON file - you could actually use jsBin to do this without changing the file system

Comment: Right, however I want to load the entities from a local file without a webserver. Thats the requirement. I think the best way will be to put the data in .js file and init the variables for the JSON and then run a loop.

Comment: @VikasSinghal what is the app scenario and how are you loading the local file and not running into CORS exceptions.

Comment: The scenario is to load the app via file:// as we need to export the whole app along with the data which has to run without a webserver. I am export data as JSON objects in a .js file.

Comment: and how many records are you talking about to want to make it faster.

Comment: If it needs to be local only, why use javascript? there are plenty of other languages that would be better suited I would have thought.  I imagine that you want it run cross platform?

Answer (score 0):

What part of the app lifecycle are these entities created? If an end-user is creating many entities thru the UI I'm not aware of making the bulk creation any faster than the way you have written.  The createEntity() method doesn't accept or output an array of entities.

If you're loading these entities on start-up and trying to improve the performance of Page_Load, I think the proper way to do to this would be to create a Lookups service that provided a JSON object of the entities, calling this service, and using exportEntities() to save the entities to a local file. You can then store this on the server and provide it to the client in a bundle or < script> tag, using importEntities() to load in the entities. You would want some versioning rules on this file to ensure the client has the most up-to-date entities.  By the way this would allow the browser to cache your lookups. (I haven't done this front-to-end yet but will soon as my application has a lot of Lookups).

In any case, I'm not aware of any way to get around the time it takes Breeze to instantiate and begin tracking these entities once the JSON data is on the client.